# Por qué muestra ambos valores del objeto?

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código, en el cual deseo recorrer sus propiedades, pero mostrar SOLAMENTE sus valores, pero me muestra su valor y la propiedad, por que ? 
***Cual es el error?***

```js
class Info{
  constructor(){
    this.words = [{
    day1: {song: "cancion",person:"persona",apple:"manzana",face:"cara",mouth:"boca",
           people: "gente",car:"auto",computer:"computador",camera:"camara",
           cellphone: "celular",phone: "teléfono",dance:"bailar",talk:"hablar",
           voice:"voz",love:"amor",cut:"cortar",kill:"matar",screen:"pantalla",
           light:"luz",charger:"cargador",element:"elemento"
          }
    }];
  } 
} 


var main = new Info(),
    i = 0,
    max = main.words.length;

for(;i<max;i++){
  for(var word in main.words[i]) {
    var currentElement = main.words[i][word]; 
    console.log(currentElement);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto te pasa porque cuando le pasamos un objeto al console.log por defecto imprime la propiedad y su valor correspondiente. Si tu quieres imprimir solo el valor puedes utilizar:

console.log(Object.values(currentElement));

```js
class Info{
  constructor(){
    this.words = [{
    day1: {song: "cancion",person:"persona",apple:"manzana",face:"cara",mouth:"boca",
           people: "gente",car:"auto",computer:"computador",camera:"camara",
           cellphone: "celular",phone: "teléfono",dance:"bailar",talk:"hablar",
           voice:"voz",love:"amor",cut:"cortar",kill:"matar",screen:"pantalla",
           light:"luz",charger:"cargador",element:"elemento"
          }
    }];
  } 
} 


var main = new Info(),
    i = 0,
    max = main.words.length;

for(;i<max;i++){
  for(var word in main.words[i]) {
    var currentElement = main.words[i][word]; 
    console.log(Object.values(currentElement));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema de tu codigo esa en lo siguiente, vamos a analizarlo paso a paso. El `for` mas externo, recorre el arreglo `words`, por tanto `main.words[i]` contiene un objeto. Ese objeto lo recorres buscando sus propiedades y te encuentras con `day1` y estas mostrando en consola `main.words[i]["day1"]` que es la unica propiedad de ese objeto, pero para lograr lo que quieres, te falta aun otro `for` que recorra todas las propiedades de `main.words[i][word]` y que imprima entonces sus valores.